# How to 'malloc' within first 4GB on x86_64

Tags: c, memory-management

Platform: Mac OS X
Lang: Obj-C/C

Is it possible to somehow make 'malloc' to allocate memory within first 4GB of process address space ?

I'm emulating i386 stack and need to guarantee that address will lie within allowed 32bit range.

Using mmap+MAP_FIXED requires to RESERVE memory before any 'malloc', it's not quite convenient. 'malloc' with constraints would be much more handy.

Comment: On Linux there is a flag `MAP_32BIT` that can be passed to mmap to request an address in the first 2 GB. Maybe Mac OS X has a similar feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible, unless you code your own implementation of `malloc` (or dive into the implementation details of some existing `malloc` then change it to suit your needs).

Most `malloc`-s implementations are using the system `mmap` (or `sbrk`) [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (see e.g. [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) on Linux, and [memory(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/memory.3.html) for MacOSX), and these are giving some arbitrary memory addresses (e.g. because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which is very useful).

PS. On Linux, you might use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_NORESERVE` or `MAP_32BIT`, but MacOSX [mmap(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/mmap) does not seem to have them.