# Allocating on a 32-bit address in macOS

Tags: macos, memory, memory-management, rust

On linux x86_64, to set up an address space with 32-bit pointers only, I use the function (In Rust):

```
let big_heap = libc::mmap(std::ptr_null_mut() as *mut libc::c_void, 
MAX_HEAP_SIZE, libc::PROT_READ | libc::PROT_WRITE, 
libc::MAP_PRIVATE | libc::MAP_32BIT | libc::MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Or alternatively pass a 32 bit value as the first argument to `mmap` and use `libc::MAP_FIXED`.

There seems to be no `libc::MAP_32BIT` on macOS. I tried setting the first argument to some constant and with `MAP_FIXED`, sometimes it works, sometimes it crashes with failure to create memory.

Is there any way to reserve an address space safely and that resides in 32-bits on macOS? I considered allocating a 64-bit value, and using 32-bit offsets from this value, but it produces unacceptable runtime overhead, having to pass the base pointer around everywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 'malloc' within first 4GB on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661393/how-to-malloc-within-first-4gb-on-x86-64)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, `MAP_32BIT` actually does exist on macOS since Catalina. It was seemingly gated behind an entitlement before `10.15.4`, but should be usable after that.

Source: https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/2ff845c2e033bd0ff64b5b6aa6063a1f8f65aa32/bsd/sys/mman.h#L155