# Cannot create anonymous mapping with MAP_32BIT on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, memory-management, mmap

I'm on a 64-bit system, but want to use `mmap` to allocate pages within the first 2GB of memory. On Linux, I can do this with the `MAP_32BIT` flag:

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    void *addr = mmap(
        NULL, // address hint
        4096, // size
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, // permissions
        MAP_32BIT | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, // flags
        -1, // file descriptor
        0 // offset
    );
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
        perror("mmap");
    else
        printf("%p", addr);
}
```

[Godbolt link demonstrating that this works on Linux](https://godbolt.org/z/fW5Maaoff). As of version 10.15, MacOS [also allegedly supports the `MAP_32BIT` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275666). However, when I compile and run the program on my system (11.3), it fails with `ENOMEM`. The mapping does work when `MAP_32BIT` is removed.

I have a few potential explanations for why this doesn't work, but none of them are very compelling:

- The permissions are wrong somehow (although removing either `PROT_READ` or `PROT_WRITE` didn't solve it).
- I need to specify an address hint for this to work, for some reason.
- MacOS (or my version of it) simply doesn't support `MAP_32BIT` for anonymous mappings.

Comment: An obvious question that isn't addressed in the post: Does it work without `MAP_32BIT`?

Comment: @kaylum It does; I can edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "zero page": on some 32-bit Unixes, the lowest page of memory is commonly configured to be inaccessible so that accesses to NULL can be detected and signal an error. On 64-bit systems, MacOS extends this to the entire first 4 GiB of memory by default. `mmap` therefore refuses to map addresses in this region, since they are already mapped to page zero.

This can be simply changed using a linker option:

```
$ cc -Wl,-pagezero_size,0x1000 test.c
$ ./a.out
0xb0e5000
```